# I need help for a definition

Tags: spoken-english, sentence-usage, writing

Does this sentence make sense, and is it correct?

“ Her honest opinion seemed very abrasive to others”

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatical. Usually, you wouldn't say that an opinion is abrasive; rather, it may be expressed abrasively.
You might say
*Some found her expression of her opinion abrasive.*